# How to run a google script based on (submit Data) from another table?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to run a google script based on (submit Data) from another table ?
The table to which the data is to be transferred is transferred by the IMPORTRANGE function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZi6U.png)

[image]

Comment: Pl. try to provide some sample data sheet or at least screen shot. And tell clearly what you want achieved, so that you can get help

Comment: I want when I click on the command save in table 1 the google apps script works
in Table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just create a script which access the two sheets and work your magic.  Make sure you add a listener to the script in the sheet which serves as trigger.

```
const sheet1_id = enter Id here
const sheet2_id = enter Id here

const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet1_id)

function run(){
  const sheet2 =SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet2_id) 
  // Do something
}
```